# is there any limit for number of relation b/w 2 nodes Neo4j 2.0.3

Tags: neo4j

hi  i am working on Neo4j 2.0.3.
I got a situation where i need to create lot of relation b/w two node (may be per day 100).
Is there any limit for number of relation b/w 2 node ?.

Comment: there is no limit between two nodes, we have nodes with millions of relationships (between them or others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a physical limit, but that should not be a problem in your cases. You can always [configure](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/kernel-configuration.html) the size of physical stores and the limit of memory-mapped of relationship records.

Comment: physical limit ??.  in my relation b/w 2 node may be 1.5 lack

Comment: Physical limit = limit on disk, that is your only real limit on the total number of relationships (in general as well as between 2 nodes).